# disable required tag in hidden divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My contact form have some div boxes which hide or show with a dropdown list. I used **required** tag in this divs. the problem is when one of this reqired tags is in a hidden div i can not submit the form what can i do ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Color").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "redd") {
        $(".box").not(".redd").hide();
        $(".redd").show();
      } else if ($(this).attr("value") == "greenn") {
        $(".box").not(".greenn").hide();
        $(".greenn").show();
      } else {
        $(".box").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();

  $("#ddColor").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "red") {
        $(".inner-box").not(".red").hide();
        $(".red").show();
      } else if ($(this).attr("value") == "green") {
        $(".inner-box").not(".green").hide();
        $(".green").show();
      } else {
        $(".inner-box").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.inner-box {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <fieldset>
    <p dir="rtl">
      <label>case1</label>
      <select id="Color" required="required">
        <option>please select</option>
        <option value="redd">home
          <option>
            <option value="greenn">laptop</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="redd box">
  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <p dir="rtl">
        <label>case2</label>
        <select id="ddColor" required="required">
          <option>please select</option>
          <option value="red">sell
            <option>
              <option value="green">rent</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="red inner-box">
    <input dir="rtl" type="text" name="pricerange" required />
  </div>
  <div class="green inner-box">
    <input dir="rtl" type="text" name="rentrange" required/>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="greenn box">
  <input dir="rtl" type="text" name="ramrange" required/>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. there is no code indicating that any input is `hidden`. do you mean that is hidden by css? 2. why it is hidden? Can you make it visible programmatically? Is all the code under you control? Please edit your question.

Comment: hi thank you for your answering. if you notice i hid or show input divs with dropdown list selection and javascript code not with css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set `required` to `false` on them when hiding, and to `true` again when showing. If **all** of the `inputs` in those divs are required when showing it's easy:

Using your `.redd` div as an example:

Hiding:

```
$(".redd").hide().find("input").prop("required", false);
```

Showing:

```
$(".redd").show().find("input").prop("required", true);
```

If only *some* of them are required, you'll want to remember their old setting and then re-apply it:

Hiding:

```
$(".redd").hide().find("input").each(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    $input.data("was-required", $input.prop("required"));
    $input.prop("required", false);
});
```

Showing:

```
$(".redd").show().find("input").each(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    $input.prop("required", $input.data("was-required"));
});
```

If you start out with some hidden in the markup, you'll want to do this before any of the `show` actions on that:

```
$("input").each(function() {
    $(this).data("was-required", this.required);
});
```

...to initialize the flag. If they all start out showing, you don't need to, because the "hide" action above will.

Comment: thank you very much for your answering i am a little confused where i have to add your codes in my javascript code? could you please show this.

Comment: @user6362236: Wherever you have `$(".redd").hide()` and `$(".redd").show()` and similar. If that's in more than one place, I'd probably put it in a named function and call that.

Comment: i have a question if i have a dropdown selection in my div boxes instead of input. this code .find("input"). does not work what can i do?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, great answer, however, you may want to edit ```$input("required", false);``` to ```$input.prop("required", false);```

Comment: @PriyankaJ - Thank you! Here on SO, when you see that kind of obvious typo, you're also welcome to just edit the fix into the post directly. At your current rep level, IIRC that will create a *suggested edit* that will go in a queue for review and approval (but the post author also gets notified and can approve it directly). Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wasn't aware of this feature.

Answer (score 0):

To remove attr you can use:

```
$('#id').removeAttr('required');​​​​​
```

Comment: thank you for your answering. i want to remove required tag based on the divs.  and i think this code can not do this.

Comment: yes...in that case you can follow @T.J. Crowder's answer...it will work :)